# Restricting access to files on Amazon S3 on per-file basis?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an interesting requirement: There's various files on the same S3 Bucket. The task is to restrict access to the files on a per-file basis using usernames and passwords.

I tried using an FTP server and s3fs for the job but the connection time is way too long. I know s3auth.com can be used to restrict access to the entire bucket, but i need to restrict access to each file (Only one randomly generated username has access to any particular file)

Comment: You should look into S3 signed URLs. Not quite a username/password, but similar results.

Answer (score 1):

Use [S3 ACLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/set-object-permissions.html). They're object (aka file) based.

> ACLs are resource-based access policies that grant access permissions
>   to buckets and objects. For more information about managing access
>   permissions with resource-based policies, see [Overview of Managing
>   Access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-overview.html) in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide.